# insertion values in database using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to insert values in my table but it doesn't work for me, what should I do?

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction($name)
  {
    return $this->render('MyAppLibraryBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
  }

  public function createAction()
  {
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
    $product->setPrice('19.99');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Id du produit créé : '.$product->getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Any exceptions? What's the value of `$product->getId()`?

Comment: i don't find any insertion in my database, what should i do please

Comment: you should add `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script then edit your question with the error messages you will be seeing

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of error is that the Product entity cannot be found by the controller. By adding the use MyAppLibraryBundle\Entity\Product; statement (assuming it is in that path) the entity can be found. If this is not the answer, please post the error message(s) you receive.

```
//with this line:
use MyAppLibraryBundle\Entity\Product;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
....

public function createAction()
{
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
    $product->setPrice('19.99');
    $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Id du produit créé : '.$product->getId());
}

}
```

Comment: Hey there. Would you explain what you changed and why it will help?

Comment: One possible source of error is that the Product entity cannot be found by the controller.  By adding the `use MyAppLibraryBundle\Entity\Product;` statement (assuming it is in that path) the entity can be found.  If this is not the answer, please post the error message(s) you receive.

Comment: I'm actually not the one who asked the question; your answer got flagged as low-quality and I was reviewing it. Before recommending deletion, I wanted to give you the chance to *edit* your answer and add content that might help it not get deleted.

Comment: that being said, I don't see any hint of namespace error in op's question, nor of the use of the product entity, so you are actually at a wild guess.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier True, a (swa)guess.  If it doesn't contribute we can delete it.

Comment: We'll let community decide about that. Maybe op will find this useful, but if I were you I'd move along, he seems long gone and reluctant on giving details about his problem...

Comment: i'm really in a big trouble, i made all steps given by this link http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.3/book/doctrine.html
but i find any insertion in my database of new values

Comment: Edit your question to show the Product entity and any error messages.  If there are no error messages, say so.